# Session null jsf getExternalContext()

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I generate a session in my code but then when using it in another file the session returns null, thx all!

this linux server primefaces,payara 5

```
public Usuarios loginUsuario(String usuario, String password) {
    Usuarios user = null;
    try {
        UsuariosDAO us = new UsuariosDAO();
        user = us.loginUsuario(usuario, password);
        if (user != null) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("usuario", user); // here set user ok! not null
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("index.xhtml");
        } else {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Atencion!", "User o Password Inconrrectos"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return user;

}
public void probarSession() {
    try {
        FacesContext esta = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
         System.err.println(esta.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("usuario")+"this is null!!!");
        Usuarios us = (Usuarios) esta.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("usuario");

        if (us == null) {
            esta.getExternalContext().redirect("login.xhtml");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: If there is nothing in your application that requires a session or nothing that requires a session is called before, there is no session. So then you should create one yourself.

Comment: I did new tests, and I realized that the problem is only in chrome does not generate the session.
if it works in firefox.
any ideas?

Comment: Besides Chrome being a <beep> browser more and more, no sorry. Check http requests for session coockies, check plugins, crwate a very mjnimal jsp page and see if it works there. Narrow things bown